# Why Phonegap build command adding all plugins?

Tags: android, cordova

Recently i have updated my Phonegap (Version - 6.4.2), JDK(Version -1.8 ), NPM(Version -4.0.5 ) and NODE (Version -6.9.2 ) also updated Android SDK to android 7

After I create new project from command line and run this command PHONEGAP BUILD ANDROID it adds all the plugins (21 plugins to be specific) but the problem is i dont want all those in my project i need only few from the available plugin, i tried manually removing unwanted plugin from command line but whenever i do run BUILD command it again adds all plugins.

Please help me resolve this

Thanks

Comment: Do you have your plugin references in config.xml or fetch.json?

Comment: No i have not explicitly written any ref in config and what is fetch.json ?

Comment: fetch.json is a file available in plugins folder that keeps track of all the installed plugin in the app

Comment: ya thanks its resolved by editing in that file

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. Have posted the answer. Please accept if its useful

Answer (score 0):

If you have plugin reference in config.XML or fetch.json available in plugins folder, plugins will get added on building platform.

Ensure to remove any unwanted plugins references in config.XML or fetch.json file to resolve the issue.